# Retrieve Files along with last modified date under a directory using shell

Tags: shell, awk

I am trying to retrieve list of files inside a (unix) directory , I want to retrieve the files along with modified date

ls -LR retrieve the files for me , but I need the modified date alone with it how do I do it ?

Answer (score 1):

Using `tree`

```
tree -D
```

Quoting from `man tree`

> -D     Print the date of the last modification time or if -c is used, the last status change time for the file listed.

Test

```
% tree -D
.
|-- [Oct 19 20:20]  dir1
|   |-- [Oct 19 19:49]  file1
|   |-- [Oct 19 19:49]  file2
|   `-- [Oct 19 19:49]  file3
`-- [Oct 19 20:20]  dir2
    |-- [Oct 19 20:20]  file1
    |-- [Oct 19 20:20]  file2
    `-- [Oct 19 20:20]  file3

2 directories, 6 files
```

---

Using `ls` followed by `awk`

```
ls -lR | awk '$9 {print $6, $7, $8, $9}'
```

Test

```
% ls -lR | awk '$9 {print $6, $7, $8, $9}'
Oct 19 19:49 file1
Oct 19 19:49 file2
Oct 19 19:49 file3
```

Comment: A  file may be present inside another subdirectory , I need list of all files inside all files subdirectory

Comment: @davidxavier then simply use `ls -lR`. See my update

Answer (score 0):

Use `find -type f -printf "<whatever>"` to print the file name plus modification date or anything else you want to know about the file. `man find`.